# Adding REST service error 'type expected'

Tags: asp.net, rest

On the word 'Description' I'm getting the error 'Type expected'

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web

Namespace SimpleRESTService
<ServiceContract()> _
Public Interface IService

    <Description("Simple echo operation over HTTP GET"), _
     WebGet()> _
    Function EchoWithGet(ByVal s As String) As String

    <Description("Simple echo operation over HTTP POST"), _
     WebInvoke()> _
    Function EchoWithPost(ByVal s As String) As String
End Interface
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Description" attribute in the WCF. Perhaps you can use this workaround:

http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2008/10/30/adding-wsdl-documentation-to-your-wcf-services.aspx